# How to send function to be executed in other form in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

i wanted to ask how can i or is it possible to send function a() (or even the function's content) from form A , to other form B and execute it in form B

Comment: Well you need to be sure how the transition should happen. Does `A` **put** a specific function into `B`. Or does `B` **get** a specific function from `A`. In eigther case you are looking for `Delegate` functions, thay can store the reference to a certain function that can later be invoked by anyone else. Also I suspect this is an `XY Problem` (parhaps try to elaborate more, what you need to do this for)

Comment: i want to create to run function remotly to server, like java RMI , and return the result back to client , i found rpc , but i  could not understand how to start

Comment: It does seem like RPC is what you need. Check out this Tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xws7132e.aspx